# Using linq to merge multiple XML files with the same structure and removing duplicates based on a key

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xslt, merge

I have multiple XML files I'm trying to merge into a single file. Linq to XML is probably the best option but I'm open to ideas (XSLT seems good at merging TWO files but is clumsy where n > 2 or n = big).

From reading other questions here, some sort of join looks good.

File1.xml:

```
<first>
  <second>
    <third id="Id1">
      <values>
        <value a="1" b="one"/>
        <value a="2" b="two"/>
        <value a="3" b="three"/>
      </values>
    </third>
    <third id="Id2">
      <values>
        <value a="f" b="foo"/>
        <value a="b" b="bar"/>
        <value a="w" b="wibble"/>
      </values>
    </third>
  </second>
</first>
```

File2.xml:

```
<first>
  <second>
    <third id="Id1">
      <values>
        <value a="2" b="two"/>
        <value a="3" b="three"/>
        <value a="6" b="six"/>
      </values>
    </third>
    <third id="Id3">
      <values>
        <value a="x" b="ex"/>
        <value a="y" b="why"/>
        <value a="z" b="zed"/>
      </values>
    </third>
  </second>
</first>
```

Merged.xml:

```
<first>
  <second>
    <third id="Id1">
      <values>
        <value a="1" b="one"/>
        <value a="2" b="two"/>
        <value a="3" b="three"/>
        <value a="6" b="six"/>
      </values>
    </third>
    <third id="Id2">
      <values>
        <value a="f" b="foo"/>
        <value a="b" b="bar"/>
        <value a="w" b="wibble"/>
      </values>
    </third>
    <third id="Id3">
      <values>
        <value a="x" b="ex"/>
        <value a="y" b="why"/>
        <value a="z" b="zed"/>
      </values>
    </third>
  </second>
</first>
```

i.e. it merges the values based on the third/@id attribute.

How do I do this elegantly with linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below is still quite ugly, and I am sure it could be brought into a somewhat more streamlined shape with a bit of work, but for now this seems to do the job:

```
public static void MergeXml()
{
    var xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\test.xml");
    var xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\test2.xml");
    var d1Targets = xdoc1.Descendants("third");
    var d2Selection = xdoc2.Descendants("third").ToList();

    Func<XElement, XElement, string, bool> attributeMatches = (x, y, a) =>
        x.Attribute(a).Value == y.Attribute(a).Value;

    Func<IEnumerable<XElement>, XElement, bool> hasMatchingValue = (ys, x) =>
        // remove && if matching "a" should cause replacement.
        ys.Any(d => attributeMatches(d, x, "a") && attributeMatches(d, x, "b"));

    foreach (var e in d1Targets)
    {
        var fromD2 = d2Selection.Find(x => attributeMatches(x, e, "id"));
        if (fromD2 != null)
        {
            d2Selection.Remove(fromD2);
            var dest = e.Descendants("value");
            dest.LastOrDefault()
                .AddAfterSelf(fromD2.Descendants("value").Where(x => !hasMatchingValue(dest, x)));
        }
    };
    if (d2Selection.Count > 0)
        d1Targets.LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(d2Selection);

    xdoc1.Save(@"c:\temp\merged.xml");
}
```

This produces the following output file from the two example input files in OPs question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<first>
  <second>
    <third id="Id1">
      <values>
        <value a="1" b="one" />
        <value a="2" b="two" />
        <value a="3" b="three" />
        <value a="6" b="six" />
      </values>
    </third>
    <third id="Id2">
      <values>
        <value a="f" b="foo" />
        <value a="b" b="bar" />
        <value a="w" b="wibble" />
      </values>
    </third>
    <third id="Id3">
      <values>
        <value a="x" b="ex" />
        <value a="y" b="why" />
        <value a="z" b="zed" />
      </values>
    </third>
  </second>
</first>
```

Comment: @IainHolder I see you have unaccepted this as the answer. A comment on why this does not/no longer answers your question would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. If it was me, it was fat fingered. The answer is excellent. The funcs were the key. I adapted it and created a for loop to munge quite a few files together. I have re-accepted the answer. :-)

Comment: Ok thanks, it had me wondering what might be wrong with it. The funcs would do well as extension methods, to clean this methods a bit up.

Answer (score 1):

This should merge the second file 'contents' into the first using LINQ.

```
       XDocument document = XDocument.Load("File1.xml");
       XElement secondElement = document.Descendants("second").FirstOrDefault();

       XDocument document2 = XDocument.Load("File2.xml");
       XElement secondlement2 = document2.Descendants("second").FirstOrDefault();

       secondElement.Add(secondlement2.Nodes());
```

**UPDATE** - Added below code to cater for unique entries in the final output.

```
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"File1.xml");
        XElement secondElement = document.Descendants("second").FirstOrDefault();

        XDocument document2 = XDocument.Load(@"File2.xml");
        XElement secondlement2 = document2.Descendants("second").FirstOrDefault();

        var startingNodes = (from n2 in secondElement.Descendants("third") select n2.Attribute("id").Value).ToList();

        var nonUniqueNodes = (from n in secondlement2.Descendants("third") where startingNodes.Contains(n.Attribute("id").Value) select n).ToList();

        secondElement.Add(secondlement2.Elements().Except(nonUniqueNodes));
```

Comment: You won't get anything like the requested `Merged.xml` file as a result, though.  You need to match up each `third` element and then compare each `value` within (as some exist in both but there's only one in the result).

Comment: @CharlesMager your correct, i missed that in the OP. Working on a correction.